# Ordering of Filter in Image Processing

Tags: image, image-processing, filtering

I wanted to ask does it matter in Image Processing in which order I apply the filter. If I apply Median Filter first and then some Low Pass Filter, will it be different if I applied Low Pass Filter first and then Median Filter?
How can we explain this conceptually?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the results will be different.  This is because a median filter is not an LTI system, and thus the operations cannot be arbitrarily reordered.

Comment: Small fix, LSI - Linear Spatially Invariant.